# 2D Shader for affecting lights based on y-distance

Tags: 2d, shaders, lighting, godot

I've been struggling with this problem for a few weeks (mostly because I'm so new to shaders), but I have an angled camera for my 2D game that uses lights.

[I saw this link](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SvyatoslavCherkasov/20181023/329151/Graveyard_Keeper_How_the_graphics_effects_are_made.php) about the '3D light simulation' and wondered how the shader responsible was written.

[image: Light's y position determines whether or not sprite is affected.]

I'm in Godot, which uses its own shader language. I just need a way to compare the y-value's of the light source and the sprite. 
I found

```
float d = (1.0 - (length(LIGHT_VEC)) + 1.0);
    float yoff = abs(VAR1.x * half_size_h / half_size_w);
    LIGHT_VEC.y += (half_size_h - VAR1.y - yoff) + z_offset;
    LIGHT = LIGHT;
```

which lowers the vector from the light to the fragment, but I couldn't get what I needed out of that.

Comment: There are quite a few different lighting effects discussed at that link. Can you describe in detail the one effect you're working on implementing in your project right now? What's the desired output appearance, how have you tried to achieve it, and how do your results so far differ from what you want?

Comment: @DMGregory I should've been clearer. Sorry, I'll edit the original question and post what I meant. It's where the sprite with the lower y-value dims the light's effects by its distance (appearing in front of the light source though it's just a lit canvas in 2D space). Then if the object moves up on the yaxis, it is lit as it normally would be (appearing behind the light source). I tried setting the global position in the shader with a uniform set by a script, but there's no way to get the light's position. I'll post my other attempt above. Thanks!